# Which CSS class will be used when using multiple classes?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to create a series of circles changing color when hovering or selecting, using jquery i try to do this.

I have styles for rating circles, chosen is green, hover is yellow, can anybody explain why both the circles become green?

```
<div class="rating-circle rating-chosen rating-hover"></div>
<div class="rating-circle rating-hover rating-chosen"></div>
```

Comment: add your jquery code as wel

Comment: It depends on the order you have written your CSS, has nothing to do with HTML class declaration order

Comment: Can you update your question with the CSS please

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, it depends in which order you've declared your `class` in CSS, for example, if you have something simple like the below code..

**HTML**

```
<div class="rating-circle rating-chosen rating-hover">test</div>
<div class="rating-circle rating-hover rating-chosen">test</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rating-chosen {
    color: red;
}

.rating-hover {
    color: green;
}
```

Here, both text will be `green` no matter in what order you declare your classes on elements in HTML document.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/oddahwx2/)